# Chupah (tallit gadol) above bimah on Shavuot

Tags: minhag, provenance, tallit-gadol, communities, shavuos

I was wondering as I hear it for the first time that one of my friend told me that they made a chupah (hung tallit gadol) above the bimah on Shavuot. He told me it's a custom that we do every year, but we never do it in our community. Can someone please tell me where this custom came and who apply it askenazi/shefardi or others? Or in short is there any signifance relayed to savuot should every community apply it?

Comment: Ty mbloch it would an honour if you could provide an answer

Comment: No source, but it's supposed to be a symbol of the wedding between Hashem and 'Am Yisrael. In other words, it represents a chuppah.

Comment: Can i have more am not satisfy i mean i dont still get it

Comment: How was the tallit hanging? On poles? Did it resemble a chuppa?

Comment: Ya may be sumthing like that but i never heard somthing done like that before

Comment: If you specifically want to know why a shul would make a chuppa on Shavuot, please edit the question to indicate this. That would make my deleted answer more relevant.